# Keras model errors out citing incompatible target shape, but model summary does not indicate it is wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wrote a model to classify text using one hot encoding. Following is my code (I have not included the imports to keep the code concise for the reader):

```
# Generate one-hot encodings for data and labels
num_labels = len(set(train_label_text))
# vocab_size = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(train_data_text)))
vocab_size = 10000
label_tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=num_labels)
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_label_text)
train_label = label_tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_label_text)

data_tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
data_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_data_text_unsplit)
train_data = data_tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(train_data_text)

# Model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(vocab_size,), activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_labels, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
x_val = train_data[:leave_alone]
partial_x_train = train_data[leave_alone:]
y_val = train_label[:leave_alone]
partial_y_train = train_label[leave_alone:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=1)
```

My model summary is as follows:

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_40 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 80008

---

## dense_41 (Dense)             (None, 14)                126

Total params: 80,134
Trainable params: 80,134
Non-trainable params: 0

---

And my data and targets are as follows:

First two records of input:
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])

First two records of output:
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

The number of values in the output matches the 14 in the model summary. However, when I run the model, I get the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_43 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (14,)

I checked examples on the web as well as some of the answers to other questions here but don't see what I am doing wrong. Is there something obvious I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: I solved the problem but for some reason my comment stating that has vanished. It turns out that I needed to use the categorical cross entropy, not the sparse categorical cross entropy for the loss function. The former is to be used when the output is a vector, and the latter is to be used when the output is just a single number.